# Looking for Regex

Tags: lightning, javascript

I am looking for a regex to replace <sup>®</sup> with <sup>MD</sup> and <sup>™</sup> with <sup>MC</sup>. Or is there any way to replace the superscript values in Javascript. 
Example value: ABC<sup>®</sup> XYZ™

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use ™ and ® to reference themselves in regex.

You mention the superscript, so I'm assuming you're referring to an html string with `<sup>` tags. This shouldn't really matter then in a regex match. If the symbol is currently superscripted and you want to replace it with more superscripted text

```
var str = yourString.replace(/™|®/g, function (x) {
    if (x=='®')
        return 'MD';
    return 'MC';
    return 'test';
});
```

Here is an example

```
<p id="demo">The Company<sup>®</sup> foundation was bought by Company Co<sup>™</sup>.</p>

<script>
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace(/™|®/g, function (x) {
    if (x=='®')
        return 'MD';
    return 'MC';
});
  console.log(res);
</script>

<!-- Outputs -->
The Company<sup>MD</sup> foundation was bought by Company Co<sup>MC</sup>.
```